# Error opening new searcher for Sitecore_master_index

Tags: solr, sitecore

Anyone help on this below error?

> sitecore_master_index: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher

Answer (score 0):

Could you go to your Solr path, for example:

**C:/Solr/scsolr-8.1.1/server/solr**

You should see a folder called Sitecore_master_index.
Can you confirm this?

If yes, could you try to go to the following path,
replacing the below in bold with your local Solr path:

https://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?auction=CREATE&name=sitecore_master_index&instanceDir=**C:\Solr\scsolr-8.1.1\server\solr\Sitecore_master_index**&config=solrconfig.xml&dataDir=data